# Match ID and filename with preg_match_all

Tags: php, preg-match-all

I' trying to match entry ID and file name with preg_match_all but can't get the second one.

`<div class="flip-entry" id="entry-8F_mU7gcLkLVGN2Rpb3FyX10JVEZ" tabindex="0" aria-label="Name:   File_Name.txt. Drücken Sie zum Öffnen die Eingabetaste.">`

I want to get `8F_mU7gcLkLVGN2Rpb3FyX10JVEZ` and `File_Name.txt` only.

Comment: What you tried so far?

Comment: it's possible to describe your code, how    you match it?

Comment: I'm trying with (.*) for both cases, works for the entry ID, but for the filename doesn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Shankar Damodaran I modified the code to this:

```
function parseHTML($url) {
    $page = getPage($url);
    $dom = new DOMDocument;
    $dom->loadHTML($page);
    $i = 0;
    foreach($dom->getElementsByTagName('div') as $tag) {
        $entryid = $tag->getAttribute('id');
        if(stripos($entryid, 'entry') !== false) {
            $items[$i]['id'] = explode('-',$entryid)[1];
            $filename = $tag->getAttribute('aria-label');
            $items[$i]['name'] = cut_str($filename, 'Name: ', '. ');
            $i++;
        }
    }
    return $items;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

#### This works for the current scenario.. Not an *ideal* solution though....

```
<?php
$str='<div class="flip-entry" id="entry-8F_mU7gcLkLVGN2Rpb3FyX10JVEZ" tabindex="0" aria-label="Name:   File_Name.txt. Drücken Sie zum Öffnen die Eingabetaste.">';
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($str);
foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName('div') as $tag) {
    $entryid = $tag->getAttribute('id');
    $fname = $tag->getAttribute('aria-label');
}
echo explode('-',$entryid)[1];
echo rtrim(explode(' ',$fname)[3],'.');
```

**`OUTPUT :`**

```
8F_mU7gcLkLVGN2Rpb3FyX10JVEZ
File_Name.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$str='<div class="flip-entry" id="entry-8F_mU7gcLkLVGN2Rpb3FyX10JVEZ" tabindex="0" aria-label="Name:   File_Name.txt. Drücken Sie zum Öffnen die Eingabetaste.">';
$preg = '/(entry-(.*)\")(\w+\.\w{2,4})/';
preg_match_all($preg, $str);
```

I think this should do...

Comment: I need to get the entry ID with the same preg_match_all, how can I include it on that regex?

Comment: You had mentioned that you where successful to get id and not file name ??